# can i create a new word:bugged program or bugged code?

Tags: word-usage

Many codes contains bugs.
can i create a new word:bugged program or bugged code ,to describe the code or program which contain bugs?
Program with bugs is more longer than bugged program.

Comment: As the answer says, "buggy" is the word you want.  "Bugged" mean that it contains a spying device.

Comment: "more longer" is a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I would call it a "[*buggy*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/buggy) program":

> 3. *informal*
>      (of a system or machine, esp a computer program) containing errors or faults